# Calling subprocess.call in Django 161 WSGI fails to execute sql update

Tags: sql-server, django, subprocess, mod-wsgi, freetds

I have a python script that I wish to kick off its process from a simple upload via CentOS6 Django 1.6.1 once the upload is complete a series of conversions and sql updates occur all of which happen in a standalone Python script. 
in my view.py I have

`subprocess.call('python /var/www/abc/123/convTest.py',shell=True)`

this successfully runs using python convTest.py and it also seems to run with the above except when it gets to the MSSQl:

`return pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;Server=%s;Database=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;PORT=1433;' % (server, dbname, user, password))
pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (20009) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

I'm assuming its a problem with WSGI permissions/scope?  since it runs without issue, converts and updates databases/tables when I run it locally via

`python convTest.py`

any ideas on best course of action?  (*side note...the process also involves esl)